# How to reload AngularJS partial template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app, main template has a drop-down list of months (Jan, Feb ...).

The main template contains an `ng-view`, loaded with partial templates using `routeProvider`.

How do I refresh the `ng-view` (by re-running its controller) from main template's controller?

So that partial template content will refresh when user switches to a different month.

Main template HTML:

```
....
<body class="" ng-controller="Main">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Route provider:

```
....
.config([ '$routeProvider', function($route) {
  $route.when('/module/:module', {
    templateUrl : 'partial/module.html',
    controller : Module
  }).otherwise({
    templateUrl : 'partial/dashboard.html',
    controller : Dashboard
  });
} ]);
```

Main controller:

```
function Main($scope, $cookies) {
    ...switch month and ajax...
    // Reload ng-view goes here
}
```

Comment: Please share your javascript and html code.

Comment: fiddle added to my answer http://jsfiddle.net/hzxNa/106/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularJS broadcast function works here...

Main template controller:

```
$scope.switch_month = function(new_month) {
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success : function() {
      $scope.$broadcast("REFRESH");
    },
    ....
  });
```

};

Each partial template controller:

```
var refresh = function() {
  .... template initialization
};
refresh(); // initialize at once
$scope.$on("REFRESH", refresh); // re-initialize on signal
```

Comment: how does this relate to your original question?

Comment: it "refresh the ng-view (by re-running its controller) from main template's controller".

Comment: you shouldnt need to rerun the controller based on a user selection, are you sure that you should be going in that direction?

Comment: My use case is little bit special, here's more details: upon switching to another month, API server state changes and will serve content relevant to the chosen month, therefore all partial templates need to re-initialize.

Comment: That is an un-angular way to do things.  the data should be loaded in via $http or $resource and mapped to your model/controller and the partial which is bound to your model/controller will automatically refresh without you having to re run the controller.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm still learning AngularJS, your advice is really useful, I am learning about $resource right now.

Comment: after learning $resource, I don't think it helps, in this scenario server state controls the visibility and availability of content (for partial templates), therefore the partial templates must re-initialize... but I see that $resource should be useful in other scenarios.

Comment: you shouldnt need to reinitialize anything.  the templates our bound and automatically update based on the data in the controller

Comment: Why you calling $.ajax({}); in angularJs? You should use angular code in angular not other.

Answer (score 2):

You should not worry about reloading the template. Since the template is loaded, the 2-way data binding in the partial template should just work whenever you change the data in the `Main` controller since the template is in the controller's scope.

You can use `$location.url('/module/:module')` to reload the view whenever you want, hence the controller will be re-evaluated.

Comment: I appreciate that, but in my use case, switching month will cause server state change, and partial template should re-initialize itself (by making API calls to server).

Comment: @HowardGuo Ok. Then you can try to put this in the callback function where the server state is successfully made. `$location.url('/module/:module')`, plugging in the correct module parameter

Answer (score 1):

fiddle included 
http://jsfiddle.net/hzxNa/106/

The fiddle has the templates in the same 'html', but you can put them into separate files as well

```
  <!-- template1.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
    Content of template1.html<br/>
    {{mydata}}
  </script>

  <!-- template2.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
      Content of template2.html<br/>
      {{mydata}}
  </script>


  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-include src="template.url"></div>
  </div>
```

you can use ng-include and bind it to the template you need

```
<div ng-include src="template" ></div>
```

where template is a variable in your controller that points to a html file which is your template